# Java generics calling a method that returns <T extends > object

Tags: java, java-8

I have a class called TResult

```
public class TResult<T extends MyEntity>  {

    public List<T> getEntityList() {
        return entityList;
    }
}
```

And I have a static method in other some class that returns it

```
public static TResult getAllEntities(final Class clazz, RouteFilter filter ){
}
```

Now, when I call getAllEntities I need to cast it to MyEntity otherwise i get a warning (unchecked assignment).
I try to change the method signature and it only works with

```
public static <T extends APIBaseEntity> TResult<T> getAllEntities(final Class clazz, RouteFilter filter) {}
```

Why do I have to point that T extends APIBaseEntity in getAllEntities method when it is already defined in TResult class signature?

```
TResult<APIBaseEntity> allEntities = GeneralCRUD.getAllEntities(APIAccount.class, filter);
```

Comment: Are `MyEntity` and `APIBaseEntity` supposed to be the same class? If yes, please edit, if no, I guess the latter extends the former, doesn't it? Please clarify.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should not use raw types*, it would help you understand what you're doing with generic classes.

Ask yourself these questions: What class is `clazz`? What kind of `TResult` are you returning? Is the provided class supposed to define the type parameter of `TResult`?

If the answer is yes to the last question, then you're probably looking for a declaration like this:

```
public static <T extends APIBaseEntity> TResult<T> getAllEntities(final Class<T> clazz, RouteFilter filter) {
    //...
}
```

This basically forces the returned `TResult<T>` to be of the same type `T` as the provided `clazz`: the type parameter of your method. This also removes the burden of casting to the return type you want, because the compiler now knows already.

> Why do I have to point that T extends APIBaseEntity in getAllEntities method when it is already defined in TResult class signature?

If you write `public <T> TResult<T> myMethod()`, `T` is a generic type for your method, but is not constrained at all, so it could be anything. `TResult<T>` does not act as a constraint for the type parameter of your method. You have to explicitly constrain it yourself, because you could even constrain it more than the `TResult` class (for instance with a subtype of `APIBaseEntity`).

If you don't constrain your method's type parameter, you get a compile error/warning (don't remember from the top of my head) because it wouldn't fit `TResult`'s type parameter declaration.

---

***Note:** *raw types are generic types referenced without their type parameter, such as* `Class` *or* `TResult`, *as opposed to* `Class<T>` *or* `TResult<T>`.

Comment: @rails What's the use of the parameter clazz in the method getAllEntities?

Comment: @gabrielgiussi It was in the OP's original code, I guess it was used in the internal code of the method to access the right table in the database, and maybe for the construction of the entity objects. In addition, here, it is precisely what allows to choose the right return type for the method, which the OP didn't use. I edited to be clearer on this aspect.

Comment: But if it only was for choose the right return type for the method, is really necessary? It will not be constrained by the method call? Like `TResult<ASubclassOfMyEntity> allEntities = GeneralCRUD.getAllEntities(filter);
`

Comment: @gabrielgiussi Yes, but I can't think of such a method in real life. How would it return something of the right type without having some runtime information about the type? (generics are erased at runtime)

Comment: Yes, generics are erased at runtime. I'm talking about a cast that could potentially throw a ClassCastException, though if that was the case one would ask himself why use Generics at all, doesn't?